# MongoDB Update with NODE-RED?

Tags: mongodb

I am in the process of trying to move data around via MQTT with MongoDB as my storage engine.

I am using Node-Red to get the MQTT data and store it as JSON objects in Mongo using the mongo node available via the node red library.

Whilst I can successfully create new documents in Mongo with each MQTT message received, I can't workout how to use the UPDATE function in order to append to existing documents. This is the usage guideline:

```
"Update will modify an existing object or objects. The query to select objects to update uses msg.query and the update to the element uses msg.payload."
```

So two questions i suppose...

How can I split the MQTT message into a msg.query and msg.payload?

Has anyone here got experience with Mongo and Node-Red that can share some examples?

Tom